# Is this the way Regex works?

Tags: regex

So I don't know exactly how to ask this question exactly but as you can see from the picture I have labelled each $replacement_number and drew a line to where it ends. The top line is what I am looking for and the bottom line is what I am replacing it with but I'm sure you all know this.

This is for an MP3 tag editor and what I am accomplishing here is it looks for exactly one letter that follows a number which may follow [anything BUT a letter] or follow JUST ONE letter and capitalize the letter that's after the number. So basically if I have 22b it will become 22B, if I have y2k, it will become y2K. But if I have yy2k it will be yy2k or if I have 2bb it will stay 2bb... etc, etc...

My question is, are the numbers in the image exactly how regex understands them or am I wrong somewhere?

Also, is my code efficient or not?

[image: regex]

Comment: Have you tried testing it? https://regex101.com

Comment: Yes, it does work. I am just wondering if it is the correct way and if I might have 1 and 2 switched.

Comment: I have a question for you: Is there some reason you couldn't figure this out yourself by simply running some tests? It would have been much faster to do so than to write all of that text, create the pretty image, and post here. It's really amazing what you can figure out by doing a little testing and experimenting on your own before you post a question here. You can find out if you have 1 and 2 switched by checking to see if what you've captured is what you expected to capture. It's really not difficult.

Comment: I already know that this works. I was just looking for confirmation that what I have is correct and whether or not my code is ~100% efficient.

Comment: When you ask a question about a regex pattern, you *must* add a tag for the programming language where it will be used.

Comment: Because MP3 tags support Unicode characters, you will probably want to rework your regular expression to use Unicode "letter" categories.  A useful discussion of Unicode character categories is at [http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Are you using Javascript regular expressions?

Comment: If you already know it works, then your question is about how to improve it, and that question is off-topic here. Questions asking for peer review of working code should be posted at [cr] instead. This site is for problems with non-working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is how the capture groups will be ordered, with all major *(and probably minor)* flavors of Regex.

If you're interested to see how exactly regex understands your pattern you can use [this nifty visualization tool](http://regexper.com/#((%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%7C%5E)%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B1%7D%7C%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%7C%5E)(%5Cd%2B)(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B1%7D)(%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%7C%24)):

[image: Regex pattern visualized]

Comment: Amazing tool! Didn't know this. Btw, you had to rotate the selfie you took with your iPhone

Comment: @ringø Didn't rotate, not a selfie, and not an iPhone... My girlfriend took that photo with a Nikon EOS 600D, and it came out upside down because lord knows why. Probably the gyroscope tripped out. We both thought it's really funny, and now I use it everywhere. Don't ruin it for me :(

Comment: Lol is your gf's name Leva? In Russian, that means left.

Answer (score 2):

you are correct, the numbers - as defined by the parenthesis (as you pictured) are exactly how RegEx will label them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11152295)

Comment: "My question is, are the numbers in the image exactly how regex understands them or am I wrong somewhere?". That was the question, I did provide an answer!